# Internationalization of Texinfo

Tags: texinfo

I am a novice user of Texinfo. I wanna know whether it is possible to write my manual, which is in Persian, using Texinfo or not. I know how to write in English but in Persian not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Texinfo supports [Internationalization](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Internationalization.html#Internationalization).

Comment: Thanks, but currently it has a limited support of i10n. It's not possible now to write in Persian using Texinfo.